# Is there any browser extension which shows the ip route of the site just opened?

Tags: browser-addons, traceroute

For example, i open up a video on youtube. Is there an extension which will show me all the hops that my connection had to make along with the latency?

the extension can be either firefox or chrome based.

Answer (score 2):

I found this extension that do the trace route:

> **WorldIP - flag and datacenter, ping and traceroute 2.2.1**
>   by Alrond
>   REAL location of web server,IP,Datacenter,Ping,Traceroute,RDNS,AS. Often shows different countries from similar add-ons,because it is based on data from core routers worldwide,and not on whois data.Real Google's data centers.Providers looking glasses

you can get it from this [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/worldip-flag-and-datacenter-pi/?src=search).

Answer (score 0):

no, this is not usually possible, because TCP packets in a connection often take differant routes to the destination, so there is no single route to show. Tracert works because its essentially a single communication through the ether , so it simulates the path that a single packet would take, but is not representative of all the packets in a complex flow like a streamed video. Such an extension would show one or more potential routes to the destination, but wouldn't necessarily show you the route that your packets are taking when trying to watch a video.

Answer (score 0):

You’re best using a third-party application to do this tracert style along with the latency etc.